# Backreferencing a repeated regex pattern using str_match in R

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, backreference

I am not too great at regex's and have been stuck on this problem for awhile now. I have biological taxonomic information stored as strings in a "taxonomyString" column in a dataframe. The strings look like this:

`“domain;kingdom;phylum;class;order;genus;species”`

My goal is to split all of the strings (e.g., “domain”) into a taxonomic level column (e.g., “domain” into a "Domain" column) . I have accomplished this using the following (very long) code,

```
*taxa_data_six <- taxa_data %>% filter(str_count(taxonomyString, pattern = ";") == 6) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(taxonomyString, into = c("Domain", "Phylum", "Class", "Order", "Family", "Genus"), regex = "([\\]\\[\\-\\p{Zs}.()[:alnum:][:blank:]]+);([\\]\\[\\-\\p{Zs}.()[:alnum:][:blank:]]+);([\\]\\[\\-\\p{Zs}.()[:alnum:][:blank:]]+);([\\]\\[\\-\\p{Zs}.()[:alnum:][:blank:]]+);([\\]\\[\\-\\p{Zs}.()[:alnum:][:blank:]]+);([\\]\\[\\-\\p{Zs}.()[:alnum:][:blank:]]+)")*
```

I had to include a lot of different possible characters in between the semicolons because some of the taxa had [brackets] around the name, etc.

Besides being cumbersome, after running through my code, I have found there to be some errors in the taxonomyString, which I would like to clean up.

Sometimes, a class name is broken up by semicolons, e.g., what should be `incertae sedis;` is actually `incertae;sedis;.` These kinds of errors are throwing off my code, which assumes that the first semicolon always denotes the domain, the second, the kingdom, and so on.

In any case, my question is simple, but has been giving me a lot of grief. I would like to be able to group each taxonomyString by semicolons, e.g., group 1 is `domain;`, group 2 is `kingdom;`, so that I can refer back to them in another call and correct the errors. In the case of `incertae;sedis;`, I should be able to call group 4 and merge it with group 5. I have looked online about how to refer back to capture groups in R, and from what I've seen str_match seems to be the most efficient way to do this; however, I am uncertain why my `([:alnum:]*;)` regex is not capturing the groups in str_match. I have tried different variations of this regexp (with parenthesis in different places), but I am stuck.

I am wondering if someone can help me write the `str_match()` function that will accomplish my goal.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
At this point, it seems like I should go with *Wiktor's* recommendation and simply split the strings by `;`'s, and then fix the errors. Would anyone be able split the strings into their own columns?

Comment: Is the number of fields fixed? If not, how do you know which fields to merge? Maybe you just need to split with `;` and then apply some custom logic?

Comment: No, the number of fields is not fixed. Ideally, I would isolate all of the errors before I split by semicolon, because the errors are not always across the same field. Sometimes, field 4 should be merged with field 5, sometimes field 5 should be merged with group 6, etc.

Comment: Can you include 5-6 examples of your data and show expected output based on that? It would be helpful if you can also include some rules of extraction.

Comment: Sure, here is one, where field 5 needs to be `Clade III;` instead of `clade;`

`Bacteria;Proteobacteria;Alphaproteobacteria;SAR11;clade;Clade;III;`

here is one where field six needs to be `marine group;`

`Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Flavobacteriales;NS9;marine;group; `

Here is one where the fields correspond to their taxonomic level (domain;kingdom;phylum),

`Archaea;Nanoarchaeaeota;Woesearchaeia;`

Comment: As for rules of extraction: I look at all of the strings with more than 6 `;`'s, and then look for patterns in the errors, e.g., `Bacteria;Acidobacteria;Acidobacteriia;Solibacterales;Solibacteraceae;(Subgroup;3);Bryobacter;   ` and `Bacteria;Acidobacteria;Acidobacteriia;Solibacterales;Solibacteraceae;(Subgroup;3);Paludibaculum;` both need to have fields 6 and 7 merged